# saving current value of a variable on page reload in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to keep a variable value on page refresh, if I have

var x=0;

but then a users does something that makes that value become

x=4;

and then the page is refreshed, is there a way to keep that value of 4 for the x variable or it will always reset to the original value?

I have written 2 functions to set and get the value like this:

```
     function SetlifeCounter()
      {
        life = 3;
        localStorage.setItem("life", life);
       }

      function GetlifeCounter()
       {
         life1 = localStorage.getItem("life");
           life1=life1-1;
         return life1;
       }
```

And then calling them this way:

```
  var mainLife;
  SetlifeCounter();
    mainLife=GetlifeCounter();
    while(mainLife!=0)
    {

        window.location.reload();
    }
```

But when I run this the page freezes...
What m I doing wrong??

P.S this is to keep track of the no. of lives in a game every time you die(page reloads) in the game life gets deducted.

Comment: Yes, use `localStorage`.

Comment: It'll always reset - you'd have to use persistent storage like e.g. `localStorage`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**.

When using persisted values, you'll need to check to see if a value was already saved (from the user's previous visit) and, if so, use that. If not, you'll need to create a value and set it into storage so that it can be used on a subsequent visit.

This is generally done like this:

```
var x = null;

// Check to see if there is already a value in localStorage
if(localStorage.getItem("x")){

  // Value exists. Get it assign it:
  x = localStorage.getItem("x");

} else {

  // Value doesn't exist. Set it locally and store it for future visits
  x = 3.14;
  x = Math.floor(x);

  localStorage.setItem("x", x); 

}
```

In your example, you have a variety of issues, but the browser locking up was due to the `while` loop, which was creating an infinite loop whenever the life count was not zero. You must be VERY careful with `while` loops and ensure that they will always have a termination condition that will be hit. But, for your purposes, this was unnecessary anyway.

See comments inline below for details on the correct usage of `localStorage`.

NOTE: This code won't work here in the Stack Overflow code snippet editor due to sandboxing, but you can see this working example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/6vwvoc71/10/)**.

```js
// This is where you will store the lives remaining
// You don't need several variables to keep track of this
// (mainLife, life, life1). Just modify this one variable as needed.
var lifeCount = null;

// As soon as the user arrives at the page, get or set the life count 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initLifeCount);

// By convention use camelCase for identifier names that aren't constructors
// and put opening curly brace on same line as declaration
function initLifeCount() {

  // You need to test to see if an item exists in localStorage before getting it
  if(localStorage.getItem("life")){
  
    // And, remember that localStorage values are stored as strings, so you must
    // convert them to numbers before doing math with them.
    lifeCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("life"), 10) - 1;
    
    // Test to see if there are any lives left
    if(lifeCount === 0){
     // Invoke "Game Over" code
      alert("Game Over!");
    }
        
  } else {
    // User hasn't previously stored a count, so they must be starting a new game
    lifeCount = 3;
  }
  
  // Any time the count changes, remember to update it in localStorage
  updateLifeCount();

  // Temporary code for debugging:
  console.log("Life count is: " + lifeCount);
}

// Call this function after the life count changes during game play
function updateLifeCount(){
  localStorage.setItem("life", lifeCount)
}
```

If you open your developer tools (F12) and navigate to view the `localStorage`, you will be able to see the value decrease every time you re-run the Fiddle. You can also see the value in the console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the updated post tell me where I'am going wrong

Comment: @caitancorreia You have several issues.... I'm working on an edit to my answer. Wait a few minutes for the update.

Comment: @caitancorreia Ok, take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many. You can choose between cookies, local storage, web sql, remote backend...

See this question about setting the value inside a cookie:

[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

For local storage, use:

```
localStorage.setItem("x", x);
```